# AWS Cloudwatch Events on Scaling In(Shutting-Down) Instance

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-cloudwatch

I created Cloudwatch Event Rule that listens to EC2 Instance-terminate Lifecycle Action and executes an EC2-RUN Command on the instance with the tag specified on the event rule. Now my question is that for example, my run command script will take 30 mins to complete is the instance will wait for the script before terminating itself?

```
{
  "source": [
    "aws.autoscaling"
  ],
  "detail-type": [
    "EC2 Instance-terminate Lifecycle Action"
  ],
  "detail": {
    "AutoScalingGroupName": [
      "_AutoScale-Site-Group"
    ]
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes. When everything goes as planned, termination is suspended while the lifecycle action executes. Once the action completes, termination proceeds. See the bottom left of this state diagram from [AWS docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/autoscaling/ec2/userguide/lifecycle-hooks.html):

[image]

That said, the nature of public cloud is that you could lose an instance anytime, instantly in exceptional situations - the 30 mins is not 100% guaranteed. If the 30 mins spindown is critical to your application, you should rethink your design. Perhaps move whatever stateful information you have on the box out to a more durable storage (database/s3 etc) more frequently.

Comment: Noted. What happens in my script is that it sync high amount of logs to s3 buckets. Thats the script that takes so long. I'm not sure why or maybe it's normal due to high counts of files. Approx 5k++ files

Comment: sure, but why are you not continuously uploading logs to s3, why does it have to become a bullk operation at terminate time? I guess it also depends on what the cost of losing those logs is - if that cost is low, it doesn't really matter.